# Object Manipulation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display all the  properties of the object Wine1 along with
their respective values .But this code is not working:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="Button" onClick="f1()">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function f1()
            {
                var Wine1=new Object();
                Wine1.color="Red";
                Wine1.price="50000 USD";
                Wine1.vine-yard="South";
                var record="Wine1<br><br>";

                for(var prop in Wine1)
                {
                    record+=prop+"="+Wine1[prop]+"<BR>";
                }
                record+="<br>";
                document.write(record);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Someone please help me to find the mistake.

Comment: replace `Wine1.vine-yard` with `Wine1['vine-yard']` and it should work fine.

Comment: @jbabey `Wine1.vineYard` would be a better replacement.

Comment: technically ["vineyard"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vineyard) is one word, if it were me it would just be `Wine1.vineyard` :P but this change and your change could have impact on other places in his code.

Comment: @jbabey Thanks.You solved my problem. Stackoverflow is an awesome site.

Comment: `record="test";` overwrites the string you carefully built! Did you mean `record += "test"?

Answer (score 8):

```
Wine1.vine-yard
```

`vine-yard` is an invalid identifier. It probably throws a syntax error. Basically, only `_`, `$` and alphanumeric characters are accepted in identifiers. An identifier is a property name or a variable name.

Also, your loop might show other properties than the ones you defined. Long story short, here is what you need to do:

```
for (var prop in Wine1) {
    if (Wine1.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        record += prop + "=" + Wine1[prop] + "<BR>";
    }
}
```

Finally, use correct indentation and spaces. It really helps a lot to read your code and see what's wrong.

Comment: Concerning "other properties", "people know better than to extend Object", but it's still a good idea to do the check.